# Create Expression working with Entity Framework out of a string

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, lambda, entity-framework-core

For a table with paging using Entity Framework I want to create simple classes that will generate an Expression-Tree, that maps to EF entities. Also, I want EF to just fetch the columns that are needed, not all columns.
So far, it basically works.

Say, we have a class like this:

```cs
public class ApplicationUserView
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

it fetches `Id` and `Email` from `ApplicationUser`-entity - this will create an Expression similar to: `x => new ApplicationUserView(){Id =x.Id, Email = x.Email };`

There is a 1:N relation between `ApplicationUser` and `Account` (like bank-accounts), so I would need something like "count the accounts for the application-user".

I created a `PaginationPropertyAttribute` so I can do something like:

```cs
public class ApplicationUserView
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [PaginationProperty("Accounts.Count")]
    public int NumberOfAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

this would add `Accounts.Count` to the expression and map to the property `NumberOfAccounts`. Also this works, and my API returns

```json
{
    "id": "f64ef618-3705-4e2d-7bcb-08dc12f0e023",
    "email": "test@te.st",
    "numberOfAccounts": 3
}
```

Now to my problem: I want the possibility to allow using methods, that still work with EF, like

```cs
public class ApplicationUserView
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [PaginationProperty("Accounts.First().Iban")]
    public string FirstIban { get; set; }
}
```

and this doesn't work currently.
It should create an expression similar to `x => new ApplicationUserView(){Id =x.Id, Email = x.Email, FirstIban = x.Accounts.First().Iban };`

so let me share/explain my code:

I want to call it like this:

```cs
IEnumerable<Column> fields = PaginationView.Inspect<ApplicationUserView>();
Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserView>> expr =
                       _getExpression<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserView>(fields);

IEnumerable<ApplicationUserView> result = await _context.Users
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x => x.Accounts)
    .Select(expr)
    .ToListAsync();
```

and this is the `_getExpression<>()` method:

```cs
protected Expression<Func<T, TTarget>> _getExpression<T, TTarget>(IEnumerable<Column> fields) 
    where TTarget: new()
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    Type targetType = typeof(TTarget);
    
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(t);

    List<MemberBinding> b = (
            from field in fields
            let memberBinding = field.GetMemberBinding(param, targetType)
            select memberBinding
        )
        .ToList();
    
    ConstructorInfo? constructorTargetType = targetType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    if (constructorTargetType is null)
        throw new MissingMemberException("no empty constructor was found");
    
    NewExpression creationExpression = Expression.New(constructorTargetType);

    MemberInitExpression initialization = Expression.MemberInit(creationExpression, b);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TTarget>>(initialization, param);
}
```

and the `Column`-class

```
public class Column : IDataField
{
    public Column(string propertyName, Type dataType, string? alias = null)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DataType = dataType;
        Alias = alias;
    }

    public string Name => Alias ?? PropertyName.Split('.').Last();
    
    public string PropertyName { get; }
    public Type DataType { get; }
    public string? Alias { get; }

    static Expression _getMethodExpression(Expression current, string methodName)
    {
        // for now, just support no-param functions
        Type innerType = current.Type.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
            .First(m => m.Name == methodName && m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
            .MakeGenericMethod(innerType);

        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(current.Type);

        Expression.Assign(param, current);

        MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(method, param);
        
        return methodCall;
    }
    
    static Expression GetPropertyPathAccessor(Expression parameter, string path)
    {
        string[] splitPath = path.Split('.');

        Expression current = parameter;
        foreach (string p in splitPath)
        {
            if (p.Contains('('))
            {
                string methodName = p.Split('(')[0];
                current = _getMethodExpression(current, methodName);
            }
            else
            {
                current = Expression.Property(current, p);
            }
        }

        return current;
    }

    public MemberBinding GetMemberBinding(ParameterExpression param, Type targetType)
    {
        Expression memberExpr = GetPropertyPathAccessor(param, PropertyName);
        MemberInfo? member = targetType.GetMember(Name).FirstOrDefault();
        MemberBinding binding = Expression.Bind(member, memberExpr);

        return binding;
    }
}
```

So something still is wrong with the `_getMethodExpression()` function.

I'm getting all kinds of exceptions..
like

> "Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Sva.Api.Data.Models.Account]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Sva.Api.Data.Models.Account]' of method 'Sva.Api.Data.Models.Account FirstAccount' (Parameter 'arg0')",

and when I change the `[PaginationProperty("Accounts.AsQueryable().First().Iban")]` use `AsQueryable` it tells me

> The LINQ expression 'NoNameParameter\n    .Select(s => s.Iban)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.",

**edit**: adding `PaginationView.Inspect`

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Column> Inspect<TPage>()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(TPage).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        PaginationPropertyAttribute? attr = property.GetCustomAttribute<PaginationPropertyAttribute>();
        string mapPath = attr?.MapPath ?? property.Name;
        string alias = property.Name;

        yield return new (mapPath, property.PropertyType, alias);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a Friday question, will help only next week. But also show `PaginationView.Inspect` method, I'ld like to test everything together.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv definetly not a Friday-question :D - updated the question :)

Comment: Instead of having an attribute, can't you have a property returning a `Func<>` or posssibly an `Expression<>`? Something like: `public Func<DbSet<Account>, string> GetFirstIbanExpression => accounts => accounts.First().Iban;`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yeah that's right... my Idea was, since it is a paging-table, to do the same with filters later, that I send the expression as string from frontend to backend. - so this is still like a spike project for this..

Comment: If you end up with dynamic client filtering, string representations of expression trees from client input seems potentially risky. What if you refactor part of some query to run in memory and an arbitrary expression tree gets compiled into a delegate and invoked? Be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IQueryable<>` is only used for the root properties on your context, to ensure that any LINQ calls capture expression trees. If you look at the actual tree for an expression like `x => x.Accounts.First().Iban`, it's not calling `Queryable.First(IQueryable..., Expression<Func<...>>)`. It's calling `Enumerable.First(IEnumerable..., Func<...>)`. This works in LINQ because the entire thing is already part of an expression tree.

TL;DR: Change `typeof(Queryable)` to `typeof(Enumerable)`.

Comment: this is one of the mistakes I did. :)  please tell me, to remove the `ParameterExpression` in `_getMethodExpression` and call the `MethodExpression` directly on the `current`-Expression. Then your answer is complete.