Assigning the result of a MethodInfo to a Property to work with Entity Framework
My target is to do a more dynamic and object-oriented entity-framework database-request.
So I wrote a class like this:
class Target
{
    [MapFrom(nameof(GetSum))]
    public int Sum { get; set; }
    public static Expression<Func<int>> GetSum(Source s) => () => s.First + s.Second;
}

my target is so create an expression like one of those:
dbContext.Table.Select(x => {Sum = x.First + x.Second })

or 

dbContext.Table.Select(x => {Sum = GetSum(x) })

so I'm trying to build the x => {Sum = GetSum(x)} when I want to assign the expression to my property:
private static MemberBinding _getMethodAssigned(
    string propertyName,              // this is Sum
    MethodInfo methodInfo,            // this is the MethodInfo of GetSum
    ParameterExpression parameter,    // this is the x
    Type type                         // this is the type Target
    )
{
    MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, parameter);
    MemberInfo member = type.GetMember(propertyName).First();
    return Expression.Bind(member, methodCallExpression);
}

which doesn't work, since Sum property is an int and the GetSum is Expression<Func<int>>. Of course, what I want, is to assign the result of GetSum to Sum.
Any idea on how to achieve this?

Does just calling dbContext.Table.Select(x => new {Sum = GetSum(x) }) work? What I mean is have you tested just your expression.

You can use LINQ Kit for such task. This my answer is almost similar to your needs. Use ExpandableAttribute.

@Magnus no it shows the same error, of course :D but I didn't find a better way to show what I want to achieve

As @SvyatoslavDanyliv commented, but not limited to LinqKit (he's just fan of it) - use some 3rd party expression injection/replacement library, writing you own is basically rewriting all they do.

@IvanStoev you think it's really necessary to use 3rd party here? for me, somehow, it doesn't seem to be a huge thing...

Well, looks like you don't understand the problem and complications then. You need a way to put custom methods or properties inside query expression tree, and then use expression visitor to replace them with actual expression. Something like string interpolation, but C# has no similar thing for expressions.

@MatthiasBurger, actually not. The same thing without LINQ Kit. A little bit code, isn't? I have big experience in that area and if we do not correct Expression Tree before passing to EF Core translator, nothing will work.

AutoMapper projections, LinqKit Expandable, NeinLinq Injectable, DelegateDecompiler (my favorite) - all they try to solve this well known problem.

What I'm hinting at is that that expression wont translate to SQL.

@Magnus, you sure? I did something like this with plain string, that worked, but would've ended up with building string to ExpressionTree myself (which was too complicated). This was my first attempt which I trashed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928094/create-expression-working-with-entity-framework-out-of-a-string

@MatthiasBurger, when you marked this answer as accepted I give up ;) But with some changes it was possible to implement.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I will try to implement it by using your link as help ;) (on the one hand 3rd party saves a lot of time, on the other hand I want to learn stuff I ain't yet familiar with and that's the way I can grow.) - thanks for sharing your link :)
